# radio button click remove error message jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, radio-button

I have multiple radio buttons in a form. I am validating those on submit of the form. So if the radio buttons are not selected, it will display error that is given in the title attribute of that radio button. Title is different for different radio buttons.
This displaying error is working fine now. Now I need to remove that error message, when the user checks the radio button. But this is not working

HTML

```
 <div class="input-container" data-validation="required">

<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="first" value="First" class="required "title="Please select first to continue."/>
<label for="first">First</label>
     <br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="second" value="Second" class="required "title="Please select first to continue."/>
<label for="second">Second</label>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="input-container" data-validation="required">

<input type="radio" name="radio2" id="first" value="First" class="required "title="Please select second to continue."/>
<label for="first">First</label>
 <br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio2" id="second" value="Second" class="required "title="Please select second to continue."/>
<label for="second">Second</label>
</div>
<hr/>
<button>Validate</button>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
$('button').click(function(){
$.each($('.input-container[data-validation=required]'), function (idx,group) {


    var current = $(group).find(':radio');
   if( !current.is(':checked') ) {
        var title = current.attr('title');
       $(group).next('ul.innererrormessages').remove();
        $(group).after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+title+'</li></ul>');
        }


    });
});
   $('.input-container .required').change(function(){
$(this).next('ul.innererrormessages').remove();
 });

});
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/26/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('.input-container .required').change(function () {
   $(this).closest('.input-container').next('ul.innererrormessages').remove();
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/31/)

Comment: Hi Palash..Thanks for ur solution..Its working fine in the fiddle. But when I put that in my code its not removing the error message.

Comment: Then there must me some issue at your end. Check if the HTML markup you have provided in the fiddle and in your code are same or not. If possible create a simple HTML page in your app add the relevant HTML markup and the jQuery code to it and test it again.

Comment: No..In my previous fiddle, it was just a portion the code..Updated fiddle with the html structure is http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/37/

Comment: @user1049057: Ok, I got the issue. Please try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/38/)

Comment: Here, we are using the `.closest()` instead of `.parent()`, based on your HTML markup...

Answer (score 0):

Write this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(".innererrormessages").remove(); // add this line to clear messages first
    $.each($('.input-container[data-validation=required]'), function......
```

Change from

```
$(this).next('ul.innererrormessages').remove();
```

to

```
 $(this).parents(".input-container").next('ul.innererrormessages').remove();
```

[Updated fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/39/)

Comment: Hi Hiral..Thanks for the reply.yea sorry I missed this line..But this will just avoid repetition of this text message. But I need to remove the error message once the user selects the radio button.

Comment: @user1049057 yes I skipped. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Hi Hiral..Thanks for ue reply..Its working fine in the fiddle. But when I put that in my code its not removing the error message.ANy idea y it is so?

Comment: yes in my previous fiddle I just gave a piece of my code..Now the complete structure http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/37/